# Execute code from Spinner's onItemSelected that's in custom listView

Tags: java, android, listview, spinner

I have a custom listView with 3 spinners. I want to execute a code in onItemSelcted but I cannot do this in adapter because some part of the code that I need to execute won't work in a adapter.

I had this code pinned to a button before but sometimes there are over 20-30 elements in the list and I need do this "automaticly" right after user picks a value from spinner to save some time.

For a button I had this code:

`((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);`

in setOnClickListener that I created inside adapter. After using this code in adapter I could exetue any code outside adapter by writing something like this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                long viewId = view.getId();

                if(viewId == R.id.button){
                    myCode(); }
```

I found no way to do something similar because there was no "link" between inside adapter onItemSelcted and outside adapter onItemSelcted. Of course writing same line of code inside adapter's onItemSelcted won't work because spinner "doesn't click".

Any idea how to solve this?

In a fewer words: I need to execute onItemSelected for a spinner that's inside custom listView element but need to do this outside the adapter in onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an CallbackInterface and create an instance of it "outside" and pass it down to the "inside", where you call the callback function with the needed arguments.

```
public interface Callback {

void onAction (int a, int b, String c);

}
```